# Update an array based on the value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, key

Iam having an array of object  named finalArr and and object named replaceJsonData. If replaceJsonData contains add =1 , then value of REQUEST_TYPE in finalArr should also become 1

```
finalArr = [{
  REQUEST_TYPE: 'add',
  TIMESTAMP: '1671636661867',
}, ]

let replaceJsonData = {
  "REQUEST_TYPE": {
    'add': 1,
    'modify': 2
  }
}
```

I tried like this way , but value itself is in the form a key

```
finalArr.map((ele)=>{
    Object.entries(replaceJsonData ).forEach(
        ([replaceDataKey, replaceDataValue]) => {
          if (ele[replaceDataKey]) {
            ele[replaceDataKey]=replaceDataValue
         }
       }
     )
});
```

Expected Output:

```
finalArr = [{
  REQUEST_TYPE: 1,
  TIMESTAMP: '1671636661867',
}, ]
```

Comment: Why not simply: `if (replaceJsonData.REQUEST_TYPE.add === 1) {
  finalArr[0].REQUEST_TYPE = 1;
}`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Presumably because the array can contain more than one element, this is just an example.

Comment: What is `replaceXMLData`? Should that be `replaceJsonData`?

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `map()` you should be using `forEach()` instead.

Comment: @Barmar - of course your assumption makes sense, but the question needs to clarify the data structures!

Comment: @RandyCasburn , if  i use  if (replaceJsonData.REQUEST_TYPE.add === 1) {   finalArr[0].REQUEST_TYPE = 1; }  
then modify =2 and delete =3,  cant use if and else here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property of `replaceDataValue` that matches the old value of the property being updated: `replaceDataValue[ele[replaceDataKey]]`

```js
let finalArr = [{
  REQUEST_TYPE: 'add',
  TIMESTAMP: '1671636661867',
}, ]

let replaceJsonData = {
  "REQUEST_TYPE": {
    'add': 1,
    'modify': 2
  }
};

finalArr.map((ele) => {
  Object.entries(replaceJsonData).forEach(
    ([replaceDataKey, replaceDataValue]) => {
      if (ele[replaceDataKey]) {
        ele[replaceDataKey] = replaceDataValue[ele[replaceDataKey]];
      }
    }
  )
});

console.log(finalArr);
```